# JavaScript RegExp: R naming conventions

Tags: javascript, regex, r, naming-conventions

We're all familiar with naming conventions in R (if not: *Venables & Smith - Introduction to R, Chapter 1.8*). Regular expressions, on the other hand, remain *terra incognita* and the most hated part in my programming life so far ... Recently, I've officially started JavaScript recapitulation, and I'm trying to create precise RegExp to check correct R object name.

***Brief intro:*** 
Object names must start with `.` or lower/uppercase letter, and if they start with `.` cannot continue with numeric... afterward, alphanumeric symbols are allowed with `.` and underscore `_`.

Long story short, here's my JS code:

```
var txt = "._.";
var inc = /^\.(?!\d)|^[a-z\.]/i;

document.write(inc.test(txt));
```

This approach manages the first part (`.` and/or lower/upper case and numeric after `.`), but I cannot pass something like `& [\w\.]`. I can write a function that will take care of this one, but is it at all possible to manage this with a single RegExp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with R or its naming conventions, but I'll give it a shot:

If you're only trying to verify that the name *begins* correctly, all you need to do is remove the `\.` from the character class, leaving you with: `/^\.(?!\d)|^[a-z]/i`. Otherwise, the `.` may still be the first character with no restrictions on the remaining ones.

If you want to verify the that entire name is correct, something like this should work:

```
/^(?:\.(?!\d)|[a-z])[a-z0-9_\.]+$/i
```

Comment: Excellent! Just to add, correct RegExp is `/^(?:\.(?!\d)|[a-z])[a-z0-9_\.]*$/i`, since `.` itself is a correct object name, though not much useful!