# Check if character value is a valid R object name

Tags: regex, r, naming-conventions

Several months ago I [asked something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331016/javascript-regexp-r-naming-conventions), but I was using JavaScript to check if provided string is a "valid" R object name. Now I'd like to achieve the same by using nothing but R. I suppose that there's a very nice way to do this, with some neat (not so) esoteric R function, so regular expressions seem to me as the last line of defence. Any ideas?

Oh, yeah, using back-ticks and stuff is considered cheating. =)

Comment: You could just try to create an object with the name and see if it works

Comment: Yeah, `tryCatch` is very close to the last line of defence.

Comment: Last line of defence. Why? It solves your problem perfectly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -- Careful, though. `assign("  _jjj", 9)` evaluates without complaint, even though `  _jjj` is not syntactically valid...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edited 2013-1-9 to fix regular expression.** Previous regular expression, lifted from page 456 of John Chambers' "Software for Data Analysis", was (subtly) incomplete. (h.t. Hadley Wickham)

---

There are a couple of issues here. A simple regular expression can be used to identify all syntactically valid names --- but some of those names (like `if` and `while`) are 'reserved', and cannot be assigned to.

- **Identifying syntactically valid names:**

  [`?make.names`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/make.names.html) explains that a syntactically valid name:

  > [...] consists of letters, numbers and the
  > dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot
  > not followed by a number.  Names such as '".2way"' are not valid [...]

  Here is the corresponding regular expression:

  ```
   "^((([[:alpha:]]|[.][._[:alpha:]])[._[:alnum:]]*)|[.])$"
  ```
- **Identifying *unreserved* syntactically valid names**

  To identify unreserved names, you can take advantage of the base function `make.names()`, which constructs syntactically valid names from arbitrary character strings.

  ```r
  isValidAndUnreserved <- function(string) {
      make.names(string) == string
  }

  isValidAndUnreserved(".jjj")
  # [1] TRUE
  isValidAndUnreserved(" jjj")
  # [1] FALSE
  ```
- **Putting it all together**

  ```r
  isValidName <- function(string) {
      grepl("^((([[:alpha:]]|[.][._[:alpha:]])[._[:alnum:]]*)|[.])$", string)
  }

  isValidAndUnreservedName <- function(string) {
      make.names(string) == string
  }

  testValidity <- function(string) {
      valid <- isValidName(string)
      unreserved <- isValidAndUnreservedName(string)
      reserved <- (valid & ! unreserved)
      list("Valid"=valid,
           "Unreserved"=unreserved,
           "Reserved"=reserved)
  }

  testNames <- c("mean", ".j_j", ".", "...", "if", "while", "TRUE", "NULL",
                 "_jj", "  j", ".2way") 
  t(sapply(testNames, testValidity))
  ```

  ```
        Valid Unreserved Reserved
  mean  TRUE  TRUE       FALSE   
  .j_j  TRUE  TRUE       FALSE
  .     TRUE  TRUE       FALSE     
  ...   TRUE  TRUE       FALSE   
  if    TRUE  FALSE      TRUE    
  while TRUE  FALSE      TRUE    
  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE      TRUE    
  NULL  TRUE  FALSE      TRUE    
  _jj   FALSE FALSE      FALSE   
    j   FALSE FALSE      FALSE   # Note: these tests are for "  j", not "j"
  .2way FALSE FALSE      FALSE
  ```

For more discussion of these issues, see [the r-devel thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Syntactically-valid-names-td3636819.html) linked to by @Hadley in the comments below.

Comment: I rather doubt that `.` is a valid variable name, and spaces seem like total madness too.  Are you sure that he didn't write `_` and had it lost in translation?

Comment: Ahh -- but `.` **is** syntactically valid.  Try `. <- 9 ; .` to see that it is.

Comment: And not only `.`, what about `..`, or even `...`? `...` has special meaning, and if you do `... <- 4`, and then `get("...")`, you'll get a correct response. This one is indeed a bit trickier than providing some nasty regexp. In this particular case `...` is stored in `.GlobalEnv`, and therefore R doesn't rant about it. But if you take a look at `?Reserved` you'll see `...` there too. Anyway, nobody stops you from assigning a value to almost any object name wrapped inside back-ticks. But, anyway, thanks for pointing to `make.names`. Me likes! =)

Comment: Not trickier than providing a regexp.  Try it to see: `grepl("^[.[:alpha:]][. [:alnum:]]*$", "...")`. It returns `TRUE`, as it should. Also, I typically detest appeals to authority, but given that Chambers is the creator of the `S` programming language, I'm gonna guess he gets this right unless someone provides a counterexample!

Comment: And don't forget `..1`, `..2`, `..3`, which can (but typically shouldn't) be used within functions to refer to the arguments matched to `...`. Try, for example, `j <- function(...) {..3}; j("a", "b", "c")`.

Comment: `isValidName("j j")` produces `FALSE` while `isValidName("j_j")` produces `TRUE`

Comment: Well, yeah... I totally agree with you on that one. BTW, regexp you provided is far from "done". There are so many weird, but syntactically valid object names, like: `._.` or so. Will check it out. `make.names` is really nice function, but it doesn't check variables, only coerces them to a valid name! =)

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for a while, until I give you the checkmark! =)

Comment: @al3xa: There's nothing wrong, syntactically speaking, with `.` or `...` as variable names. It's the *parser* that assigns `...` a special meaning.

Comment: make.names is the correct way to do this.  I asked on r-devel some time ago: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Syntactically-valid-names-td3636819.html

Comment: @hadley, damn, I really need to comb down R mailing list thoroughly... =/ Thanks anyway!

Comment: It would be useful to add `TRUE` or `NULL` to `testNames`.  Also `isValidNames` isn't quite right because it returns T for `.1`.

Comment: @hadley -- Thanks! Just fixed the regular expression and added `TRUE` and `NULL`. (Guess I was right to distrust appeals to authority, as mentioned in my comment above!)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Added challenge: which unicode characters are valid variable names? `ü <- 1` works, but `£ <- 1`.  (The regular expression may already work depending on what exactly a letter is)

Comment: `isValidName('.')` => `FALSE`. I’ve taken the liberty of fixing this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 6):

As Josh suggests, `make.names` is probably the best solution to this. Not only will it handle weird punctuation, it'll also flag reserved words:

```
make.names(".x")   # ".x"
make.names("_x")   # "X_x"
make.names("if")   # " if."
make.names("function")  # "function."
```

Comment: +1 -- Thanks for this and for your comments. You really helped me zero in on the distinction between reserved and unreserved names (both of which are _syntactically_ valid).