# Variable name restrictions in R

Tags: r, r-faq

What are the restrictions as to what characters (and maybe other restrictions) can be used for a variable name in R?

(This screams of general reference, but I can't seem to find the answer)

Comment: R FAQ 7.14: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f

Comment: You might also be interested in the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396577/check-if-character-value-is-a-valid-r-object-name/8396658#8396658

Comment: You should have found the link to `?make.names` in the help page for `read.table`. The help page I always have difficulty remembering is the one that describes the allowable escape characters and the answer is `?Quotes`.

Comment: An Introduction to R, [Section 1.8: R commands, case sensitivity, etc.](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You might be looking for the discussion from `?make.names`:

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or
>   underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed
>   by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the
>   reserved words.

In the help file itself, there's a link to a list of reserved words, which are:

> if else repeat while function for in next break
>
> TRUE FALSE NULL Inf NaN NA NA_integer_ NA_real_ NA_complex_
>   NA_character_

Many other good notes from the comments include the point by James to the [R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f) addressing this issue and Josh's pointer to a related SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396577/check-if-character-value-is-a-valid-r-object-name/8396658#8396658) dealing with checking for syntactically valid names.

Comment: Note that you could use anything if you quote your variable name, eg ``TRUE` <-2` is valid. I can't write this properly using the SO syntax :(

Comment: Of course, my problem was I was searching Google for the inverse ("restrictions") or basically *invalid* characters when I should have been searching for *valid* characters.

Comment: Also, a dot on its own is valid. `. = 3; print(.)`

Comment: What's the meaning of a name starting with a dot? I've seen many in R packages.

Comment: @skan It is usually done in an attempt to avoid name collisions with common names of variables, columns of data frames, or other arguments passed along to different methods or other functions.

Answer (score 28):

Almost NONE! You can use 'assign' to make ridiculous variable names:

```
assign("1",99)
ls()
# [1] "1"
```

Yes, that's a variable called '1'. Digit 1. Luckily it doesn't change the value of integer 1, and you have to work slightly harder to get its value:

```
1
# [1] 1
get("1")
# [1] 99
```

The "syntactic restrictions" some people might mention are purely imposed by the parser. Fundamentally, there's very little you can't call an R object. You just can't do it via the '<-' assignment operator. "get" will set you free :)

Comment: Are there _literally_ no restrictions using `assign` and `get`, or do you run into some limitations at some point?

Comment: I believe the phrase is "Enough rope to hang yourself with" :-P

Comment: ?assign: "There are no restrictions on ‘name’: it can be a non-syntactic name (see ‘make.names’).". This is of course a lie: c=paste(rep(letters,10000),collapse="") ; assign(c,123) produces: Error in assign(c, 123) : variable names are limited to 10000 bytes

Comment: @joran -- From `?name`, "Names are limited to 10,000 bytes (and were to 256 bytes in versions of R before 2.13.0).", so there's at least one limit for you!

Comment: @joran You could start the slow descent into madness though: `assign("get",ls)`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien A limit presumably only reached by German or Welsh programmers, with their love of compound words. :)

Comment: You don't need `get()`, backtick quoting the name will reference it fine: `` `1` ``

Comment: good point, also works when assigning, so you don't need assign either

Comment: You guys are playing some dangerous games there.

Answer (score 6):

The following may not directly address your question but is of great help.
Try the `exists()` command to see if something already exists and this way you know you should not use the system names for your variables or function. 
Example...

```
   > exists('for')
   [1] TRUE

   >exists('myvariable')
   [1] FALSE
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted, to me it is in any case a usable piece of information.

Answer (score 2):

Using the make.names() function from the built in base package may help:

```
is_valid_name<- function(x)
{
  length_condition = if(getRversion() < "2.13.0") 256L else 10000L
  is_short_enough = nchar(x) <= length_condition
  is_valid_name = (make.names(x) == x)

  final_condition = is_short_enough && is_valid_name
  return(final_condition)
}
```