# dplyr "Select" - Error: found duplicated column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to extract columns from a DT to a new DT using select{dplyr}

```
extract_Data <- select(.data = master_merge, subjectID, activity_ID,
                           contains("mean\\(\\)"), contains("std\\(\\)"))
```

There are 563 columns so I am asking to extract the first and second column (subject, activity) and all other columns where mean() or std() is present.

There are NO duplicate columns that can be created here. so stumped as to the why. I have tried every variation of select but always Error: Duplicated Column name.

How can I troubleshoot this - I have gone through all 563 columns names and there are no duplicates.

Comment: What if you do `matches("(mean|std)\\(.*\\)")` instead of the two current `contains` statements? ... edited to use `matches` instead of `contains`

Comment: same error "Error: found duplicated column name"

Comment: With `matches` as well?

Comment: Can you reduce the problem to a size where the error still occurs and you can provide the column names of your data set?

Comment: Yes - with matches as well.

Comment: Include that in your question, not in the comments please.

Comment: I think `which(duplicated(names(master_merge)))` will eliminate one suspect

Comment: Ran which... looks like it returns the index of the cuplrits. It did return duplicates - but they really aren't - fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8"           "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-9,16"

Comment: No sense in continuing in the comments and under possible answers. Provide a reproducible example and ambiguity will disappear.

Answer (score 34):

The root of the problem is invalid characters in the original column names.   The discussion in [Variable Name Restrictions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195718/variable-name-restrictions-in-r)   applies to column names, too.  Try forcing unique column names with *valid* characters, with make.names() .

```
valid_column_names <- make.names(names=names(master_merge), unique=TRUE, allow_ = TRUE)
names(master_merge) <- valid_column_names
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Very concise and generalizable.

Answer (score 12):

Here is the solution I have found :

```
data <- data[ , !duplicated(colnames(data))]
```

This subsets the dataset without all the duplicated columns.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

Duplicates out of match filter can cause "duplicated name" error. Example:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(1, 2, 3)
names(x) <- c("a", "a", "b")

x %>%
  select(matches("b"))
```

If you don't need those columns, eliminate them with

```
x <- x[ !duplicated(names(x)) ]
```

Comment: That is clear - what I do not understand is why this is being returned as a duplicate - fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8"           "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-9,16"  and "fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-1,24"         "fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()-25,48"

Comment: but they are not duplicates!

Comment: `duplicated` function doesn't return the first occurence of the duplicate. Try `which(names(master_merge) == "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()-1,8")`

Comment: it does return duplicates. sorry.

Comment: I've seen this error, too.  When I checked which column names were considered duplicates with the duplicated() function, it looks like the numeric characters after the "-" (possibly including "-",) are ignored.  The functions seem to be treating the column names as if they were multiple copies of "fBodyAcc-bandsEnergy()" , multiple copies of "fBodyGyro-bandsEnergy()", etc.   without the "-1,8" and "-9,16" that do make the column names unique.   I don't have an answer yet to how to fix the issue, just offering this clue why you're seeing that error when there are no actual duplicated columns.

Comment: Update: the problem is invalid characters in the column names.  I posted a new answer with details and a solution based on a related SO question.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but this will help a lot of people.

For all you Coursera students facing this problem with this dataset: there *are* duplicate column names. For example, 'fBodyAccJerk-bandsEnergy()-1,16' is found twice. Check:

> your_merged_data_with_column_names[,400:420]

I'd love to show the output, but my browser won't support the 'code' button nor the ctrl-K shortcut and there's too much data to indent by hand. Try this code for yourself and carefully check the 'Variables not shown'!

I am working on a solution right now myself, possibly using the above answers, or the course forum.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Lantana great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28576595/3888000), here is a function for a pure `dplyr` solution with `pipe` integration :

```
validate.names = function(df){
  rtn = df
  valid_column_names = make.names(names=names(df), unique=TRUE, allow_ = TRUE)
  names(rtn) = valid_column_names
  rtn
}
```

You can then use it like this :

```
extract_Data %>% validate.names
```

Answer (score -1):

I was puzzled by the same error. Avoid using select. If  meanStdcolumns is the list of columns containing mean or std (which you can get using grep), then master_merge[,meanStdcolumns] seems to work.

Answer (score -3):

Before you assign the column names filter out the columns by getting a list of indices using

```
meanStdColumns <- grep("mean|std", features$V2, value = FALSE)
```

and then assign the columns names using

```
meanStdColumnsNames <- grep("mean|std", features$V2, value = TRUE)
```