# Create a data frame with date as column names

Tags: r

I would like to construct a data table in R that has columns as dates and rows as times (without date info). Basically I have a table in the form:

```
Time  21.04.15 22.04.15 24.04.15 03.05.15
00:00      0.4      0.4      0.4      0.4
01:00      0.4      0.4      0.4      0.4
02:00      0.4      0.4      0.4      0.4
03:00      0.6      0.6      0.6      0.6
04:00      0.6      0.6      0.6      0.6
05:00      0.7      0.8      0.8      0.8
06:00      0.7      0.8      0.8      0.8
07:00      0.7      0.8      0.8      0.8
...
```

I would like to address (plot, extract) the columns by date and elements by date and time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not clear about the expected output.  Have you tried `melt` or `t`

Comment: Have you seen [this previous Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195718/variable-name-restrictions-in-r)? I think the short A is yes, you can, but you might consider using a long format with date and time as columns and a value column for your observations instead. See the [Introduction to Tidyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) for more on that.

Comment: I do not want to reshape the data. I would like to address this elements of the table as: `data["2015-04-15"]` or `data["2015-04"]`.

And even more - plot `data["2015-04-15"]` as time series.

Comment: It's not that different to `data[data$date=="2015-04-15", ]` which allows the data to be in long format and makes just about everything easier. You're welcome to your own opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is rename them character strings that represent dates, but I don't think the names themselves can be a `Date` object. (I'll admit, I've never tried, and I'm not going to experiment with it because doing so seems like a really bad idea).

Assuming your current column names are in dd.mm.yy format, run

```
names(df_object) <- format(as.Date(names(df_object), format = "%d.%m.%y"),
    format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

But like those in the comments, while this will work, I have a hard time imagining circumstances where it is beneficial.

Comment: Thanks. I will be able to do everything - compare dates - with dates as character string.