# Convert string to variable name in R

Tags: r, string, variables, type-conversion

I have spend hours to look for a proper solutions but I found nothing on Internet. There is my question. In R, I have a specific list of characters containings my desired variable names ("2011_Q4", "2012_Q1", ...). When I try to assign a dataset to each of this name with a loop, it does work but the output it's strange. Indeed, I have

```
> View(`2011_Q4`)
```

instead of

```
> View(2011_Q4)
```

And I don't know how to remove this apostrophe. It's very annoying since I have to type this ` in order to call the variable.

Somebody can help me? I would appreciate his help.

Thanks a lot and best regards

Comment: naming convention (rules for valid object names)!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195718/variable-name-restrictions-in-r

Comment: hello, can you post the code that you used to assign the variable ?

Comment: sure, thanks a lot for helping me. I have tried many things but...
for (i in 1:1){
  assign(list[i],read.csv(file.path("given path",
                                       list[i]), header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, sep=";"))
}

as the names are in list

Comment: What’s the problem with entering the backticks? I don’t see that as a big annoyance (in fact, it’s fairly common in my code).

Comment: are you talking variables (sort of coumn names in data.frames representing variables and rows representing observations) or are you talking objects? my guess from the View() command is that you want to create objets e.g. data.frames with these respective names?

Comment: Exactly then when I want to call the variable, I always have to write those ` otherwise I got 
    > 2011_Q4
    Error: unexpected input in "2011_"
but if I write 
    `2011_Q4`

then it works, do you know why?

Comment: Because those are the rules in R. Variable names must start with a letter or a dot, they cannot start with a digit. Simple enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, it's a backtick (`), not an apostrophe ('). In R, backticks occasionally denote variable names; apostrophes work as single quotes for denoting strings.

The issue you're having is that your variables start with a number, which is not allowed in R. Since you somehow made it happen anyway, you need to use backticks to tell R not to interpret `2011_Q4` as a number, but as a variable.

From `?Quotes`:

> #### Names and Identifiers
>
> Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period (.)
>   and the underscore. They must not start with a digit nor underscore,
>   nor with a period followed by a digit. Reserved words are not valid
>   identifiers.
>
> The definition of a letter depends on the current locale, but only
>   ASCII digits are considered to be digits.
>
> Such identifiers are also known as syntactic names and may be used
>   directly in R code. Almost always, other names can be used provided
>   they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick (`), and deparse
>   will normally use it, but under many circumstances single or double
>   quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to
>   a name). One place where backticks may be essential is to delimit
>   variable names in formulae: see formula.

The best solution to your issue is simply to change your variable names to something that starts with a character, e.g. `Y2011_Q4`.

Comment: Dear alistaire,
Thanks a lot for your great remarks and comments. It helped me a lot. I am sorry for this confusion but your advices are more than welcomed. 
Have a nice afternoon and best regards