# Sanitize strings for unique legal symbols in R

Tags: r, symbols, gsub

I want to clean up strings so they can be parsed as unique legal symbols. I intend to clean up a lot of strings, so there is an undesirable risk of duplicated symbols in the output. It would suffice to take every illegal character and replace it with its base 32 encoding. Desired behavior:

```
sanitize("_bad_symbol$not*a&list%$('")
## [1] "L4bad_symbolEQnotFIaEYlistEUSCQJY"
```

I think all I need is a complete list of possible characters to `grep` for. I know about `letters` and `LETTERS`, but what about everything else?

Does a better solution already exist? Because I would love that.

**EDIT**: just found about `make.names()` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195718/variable-name-restrictions-in-r). I could go with that in a pinch, but I would rather not.

Comment: *"Does a better solution already exist? Because I would love that."* seems to contradict *"I could go with [`make.names`] in a pinch, but I would rather not."* What is unsatisfactory about `make.names`? Maybe you can modify the code of `make.names` to meet your needs?

Comment: You're right. I was too fixed on a different solution. Just found `make.unique()` too, and `make.unique(make.names(...))` actually solves the problem quite nicely.

Comment: `make.names()` alone would introduce conflicts. That was the unsatisfactory bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `make.names()` and `make.unique()` together, the problem is solved.

```
make.unique(make.names(c("asdflkj#@#$", "asdflkj####")))
## [1] "asdflkj...."   "asdflkj.....1"
```

Comment: Also: `make.names(..., unique = TRUE)`. Just learned about that one.