# Replace all underscores in feature names with a space

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to replace all underscores in a dataframes feature names with a space:

```
library(tidyverse)
names <- c("a_nice_day", "quick_brown_fox", "blah_ha_ha")
example_df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:3,
  y = LETTERS[1:3],
  z = 4:6
)
names(example_df) <- names
```

Tried:

```
example_df %>% rename_all(replace = c("_" = " "))
Error: `.funs` must specify a renaming function
```

Also tried:

```
example_df %>% rename_all(funs(replace = c("_" = " ")))
Error: `nm` must be `NULL` or a character vector the same length as `x`
```

How can I replace all the underscores in the feature names with a space?

Comment: You want your column names to contain spaces? That's generally a really bad idea for working with the data. It makes it much messier to have to quote the column names when using `mutate()` and such. Are you sure you need that?

Comment: Names are not allowed to contain blanks.  See [Variable name restrictions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9195718/4752675)

Comment: @MrFlick Understood but for this particular use case it's for passing to ggplot and making use of str_wrap so that the column labels are readable :)

Comment: @DougFir Well, since it's really a ggplot issue, you probably should have started with that code. It would probably be easier to change the scales of the ggplot object rather than mutate the data itself.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the tip. For more context, what I have is a dplyr chain using group by and then quite a few aggregation functions sum, count etc. These newly created features all have underscores in place of spaces. I'm then passing this df to ggplot and using a facet grid so the names that I created in my function look too squished in all the chartlets produced by the facet grid. So, I was going to use str_wrp() on the df feature names after replacing "_" with " ". Is there a more standard approach here?

Comment: Normally the facets are labeled with values in columns, not the actual column names. Are you also reshaping your data? Seems like you might be leaving something else out because I don't see how that's possible otherwise. It would have been helpful to have an example demonstrating this particular problem to make it more clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about:

```
example_df %>% select_all(funs(gsub("_", " ", .)))
```

Output:

```
  a nice day quick brown fox blah ha ha
1          1               A          4
2          2               B          5
3          3               C          6
```

You could also use `rename`, however in this case you'd need to call it in a different way:

```
example_df %>% rename_all(function(x) gsub("_", " ", x))
```

Or simply:

```
example_df %>% rename_all(~ gsub("_", " ", .))
```

Answer (score 4):

With base R:

```
colnames(example_df) <- gsub("_", " ", colnames(example_df))
```

Comment: colnames(example_df) <- gsub(" ", "_", colnames(example_df))